# T-SQL: How to make cell-values unique?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have a table where **the cells in a column should not have the same values**, how do I check this and update? (I know I can set constraints in the settings, but I don't want to do that.)

Say the column name is called *unique hash name* and contains

```
Peter
Peter
Peter
Dave
Dave
```

and so on. I want that to transform to:

```
Peter
Peter1
Peter2
Dave
Dave1
```

What is the T-SQL for SQL Server to do that?

**Update**: For clarity's sake, let's call the table "Persons" and the cell I want unique "UniqueName". Could you make it a SELECT-statement, so I can test the result before updating. And I am using **SQL Server 2005 and above**.

Comment: Is this SQL Server 2005? If so, you just run the "inner select" statement of my very simple and clean example below... you'll have what you want.

Comment: You should specify your version of SQL Server (2000, 2005) to get faster response.

Comment: At this point it doesn't matter either way... I have posted a 2000 and 2005 solution... the 2000 one will work on both version (and sql 7 and 2008... why not).

Comment: @Seb: At least for me the question was misleading it it's original state, I changed it to be closer to what you seem to want. Roll back if you feel like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: I've changed the query to use your field names and added a "select-only" query for you to preview.

This is actually pretty easy to do... just use ROW_NUMBER() with a PARTITION clause:

```
UPDATE Persons SET UniqueName = temp.DeDupded FROM
    (SELECT ID,
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (PARTITION BY UniqueName ORDER BY UniqueName) = 1 THEN UniqueName
        ELSE UniqueName + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (PARTITION BY UniqueName ORDER BY UniqueName)-1) END AS DeDupded
    FROM Persons) temp
WHERE Persons.ID = temp.ID
```

If you want a "select-only", then here you go:

```
SELECT ID,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (PARTITION BY UniqueName ORDER BY UniqueName) = 1 THEN UniqueName
    ELSE UniqueName + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER (PARTITION BY UniqueName ORDER BY UniqueName)-1) END AS DeDupded
FROM Persons
```

---

EDIT Again: If you're looking for a SQL Server 2000 Solution...

```
CREATE TABLE #Persons ( ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), UniqueName VARCHAR(100) )

INSERT INTO #Persons VALUES ('Bob')
INSERT INTO #Persons VALUES ('Bob')
INSERT INTO #Persons VALUES ('Bob')
INSERT INTO #Persons VALUES ('John')
INSERT INTO #Persons VALUES ('John')

SELECT
    ID,
    CASE WHEN Position = 0 THEN UniqueName
        ELSE UniqueName + (CONVERT(VARCHAR, Position))
    END AS UniqueName
FROM
    (SELECT
        ID,
        UniqueName,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Persons p2 WHERE
            p1.UniqueName = p2.UniqueName AND p1.ID > p2.ID) AS Position
    FROM
        #Persons p1) _temp

DROP TABLE #Persons
```

Comment: You should mention that this is SQL Server 2005 and higher only.

Comment: Maybe you should down-vote solutions that do not work, and not those that you just don't happen to like. If you want to be proud of something go ahead and build a solution that's just as simple *and* works on SQL Server 2000.

Comment: True, your solution did produce the eventual end result, but an answer gets voted for it's means as well as it's end.

Comment: Talking of the means - your solution processes *rows*. I think the question was about data being the same across *columns*.

Comment: BTW, I realize that sounds very prickish (and I appologize for that). You're obviously great with SQL (looked at your posts), so I think I was being a bit more harsh on your post. To me, seeing "you have to use cursors" is like a matador waving his cape at a bull.

Comment: "Cells in a column"... I think he means a single column, multiple rows. I could very well be wrong though.

Comment: I said "probably". Well... Reading the question again I'm not so sure myself anymore. My solution made column values unique across each individual record, not across one column. That would have been easier indeed.

Comment: @TimothyKhouri, beautiful solution. However, one thing it doesn't address is the length of a column. It also doesn't address the potential of "Peter1" already existing when there are multiple row with "Peter" value.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a pretty clear use-case for a [trigger](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/create_8.htm) (insert,update).